# how to call multiple methods in onClick in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components (Parent component & Child component) in my react app. I have two button clicks in my child component and I need to pass two props to the parent component. I use the code as follows.
The problem is, I can't include both methods in the parent component's  element, but I need to. How can I use both edituser and deleteuser functions in the parent component?

Child component:

```
class EnhancedTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userID: 10
    };
    this.editByUserId = this.sendUserId.bind(this);
    this.DeleteByUserId = this.sendUserId.bind(this);
  }

  editByUserId() {
    this.props.onClick(this.state.userID);
  }

  DeleteByUserId() {
    this.props.onClick(this.state.userID);
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <button onClick={this.sendUserId}>
           <BorderColorIcon onClick={this.editUserById} className="action margin-r" />
           <DeleteIcon onClick={this.deleteUserById} className="action margin-r" />
       </button>
    )
  }
}
```

Parent component:

```
Import EnhancedTable from './EnhancedTable';

class Users extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userID: null
    };
    this.editUser = this.editUser.bind(this);
    this.deleteUser = this.deleteUser.bind(this);
   }

  editUser(idd) {
    this.setState({
      userID : idd
    })
    console.log("User Edited");
  }

   deleteUser(idd) {
      this.setState({
        userID : idd
      })
      console.log("User Deleted");
    }

  render() {
     return(
         <EnhancedTable onClick = {(e)=>{this.editUser; this.deleteUser;}}/>
     )
   }
}
```

Comment: You may create another function and move all the functions to be called in it and reference it in JSX `onClick` attribute.

Comment: I did that and then console says that idd is not defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed your ()

```
<EnhancedTable onClick = {(e)=>{this.editUser(); this.deleteUser();}}/>
```

Comment: That is because you declare `editUser = this.onFillForm.bind(this);` in your constructor

Comment: Yes. Because
this.editUser = this.onFillForm.bind(this);
onFillForm is not there. So this.editUser is undefind

Comment: I updated my code. but still it says this.editUser is not a function

Comment: @safwanmoha after editing the code, both functions are firing to each button click

Comment: Oh! It's totally different what you are asking

<EnhancedTable editUser={this.editUser} deleteUser={this.deleteUser}/>

you have to pass it this way in to the component. But your question is asking for a different thing

Answer (score 4):

You are doing it right in

```
 <EnhancedTable onClick = {(e)=>{this.editUser; this.deleteUser;}}/>
```

A minor change is needed:

```
<EnhancedTable onClick = {(e)=>{this.editUser(e); this.deleteUser(e);}}/>
```

A quick reference for what changed here:

```js
let x = () => {
 console.log('hello');
}

x; // This simply does nothing as it is just a reference to the function

x(); // This instead invokes the function
```

Comment: when I do this, output is repeating as an infinite loop

Comment: And after doing this, both console,logs are firing for deleteUser() only